# How to use INDIRECT in the condition of SUMIF?

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-indirect

The first column of my worksheet contains some categories (e.g. `A1: Food`). I'd now like to use these typed words in the condition of a SUMIF in the second column (e.g. `B1: =SUMIF(C1;"Food";D1`). However, I don't want to retype them again.

Is it possible to use `INDIRECT` in this case? I tried `=SUMIF(C1;INDIRECT(A1);D1)`, but that didn't work, although I don't get an error message.

Comment: For that you shouldn't need `Indirect`, if you're trying to sum for each value that is "Food", it should just be `=SUMIF(C1;A1;D1)`

Comment: Oh, that's stupid. I had to work quiet a lot with `INDIRECT` lately and it just didn't cross my mind to remove it. You can add that as an answer @JohnBustos. Thanks! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the sake of an answer:

> For that you shouldn't need Indirect, if you're trying to sum for each value that is "Food", it should just be:

```
 =SUMIF(C1;A1;D1)
```

Courtesy [John Bustos](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26663879/how-to-use-indirect-in-the-condition-of-sumif).